# MySQL Group By and Custom Order By

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a table like this:

```
Country  Currency  sort
Taiwan   TWD       1
Taiwan   USD       2
Egypt    USD       2
Egypt    EGP       1
Japan    JPY       1
```

I need to select all the currency that I can use in Taiwan and Egypt
But I need to sort by country Egypt first then Taiwan, then by field sort

So I need the result be:

```
Currency
EGP
USD
TWD
```

First time I use UNION, but I found I can't sort by my sort field

```
SELECT Currency
 FROM CurrencyUse
 WHERE country = 'Egypt'
 UNION 
SELECT Currency
 FROM CurrencyUse
 WHERE country = 'Taiwan'
```

Second Try I use group by

```
SELECT Currency
 FROM CurrencyUse
 WHERE Country IN ('Egypt','Taiwan')
 GROUP BY Currency
 ORDER BY FIELD(Country,'Egypt','Taiwan') , sort
```

But the row USD use Taiwan row's data, result is not what I want :'(

Comment: "First time I use UNION, but I found I can't sort by my sort field" Why not?

Comment: SELECT Currency FROM CurrencyUse WHERE country IN('Egypt','Taiwan') ORDER BY currency,sort

Comment: @Strawberry
I did
(SELECT Currency
 FROM CurrencyUse
 WHERE country = 'Egypt'
 ORDER BY sort
 UNION 
(SELECT Currency
 FROM CurrencyUse
 WHERE country = 'Taiwan'
ORDER BY sort) 
result stille  USD,EGP,TWD